# Problema para insertar línea horizontal en éste conjunto de tres gráficas matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

Con los datos del DataFrame **filter_df** Construyo el siguiente conjunto de gráficos.

```
diccionario_datos = {'Close': {'2021-01-04': 128.26499938964844,
  '2021-01-05': 129.85081481933594,
  '2021-01-06': 125.47985076904297,
  '2021-01-07': 129.76162719726562,
  '2021-01-08': 130.8816375732422,
  '2021-01-11': 127.83878326416016,
  '2021-01-12': 127.66038513183594,
  '2021-01-13': 129.73190307617188,
  '2021-01-14': 127.76942443847656,
  '2021-01-15': 126.01507568359375},
 'EMV': {'2021-01-04': 1.1217349456341117,
  '2021-01-05': 0.9685423253032684,
  '2021-01-06': 0.06249889663636957,
  '2021-01-07': 0.1247366530747543,
  '2021-01-08': 0.2426310029138631,
  '2021-01-11': 0.12634571574287928,
  '2021-01-12': 0.38861895537837793,
  '2021-01-13': -0.44504611347533796,
  '2021-01-14': -0.4042320069228375,
  '2021-01-15': -0.873122996134412},
 'Volume': {'2021-01-04': 143301900,
  '2021-01-05': 97664900,
  '2021-01-06': 155088000,
  '2021-01-07': 109578200,
  '2021-01-08': 105158200,
  '2021-01-11': 100384500,
  '2021-01-12': 91951100,
  '2021-01-13': 88636800,
  '2021-01-14': 90221800,
  '2021-01-15': 111598500}}

filter_df = pd.DataFrame(diccionario_datos)

# Creating figure with two rows and one column
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 8))

# Plotting close prices on the first sub-plot
ax1.plot(filter_df['Close'], color='purple', lw = 1)
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_title('Prices')

# Plotting trading volume on the second sub-plot
# Calculating the mean value of close prices
mean_volume = np.mean(filter_df['Volume'])

ax2.bar(filter_df.index, filter_df['Volume'])
# Plotting the horizontal line along with tmean volume
#ax2.axhline(EMV_mean, color = 'r', linewidth = 2, linestyle = '--')
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_title('Volume')

# Plotting close prices on the first sub-plot
ax3.plot(filter_df['EMV'], color='purple', lw = 1)
ax3.grid(True)
ax3.set_title(' EMV')
ax3.grid(True)

plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

Me devuelve

[image: Gráfica sin línea media]

En la última gráfica, necesito insertar una línea con el valor de la media de todos los datos de esta gráfica, para ello utilizao la sentencia siguente.

```
ax2.axhline(EMV_mean, color = 'r', linewidth = 2, linestyle = '--')
```

La línea no aparece en la gráfica.

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Si es la última gráfica... ¿no sería `ax3`?

Comment: Efectivamente, por eso habia intentado cancelar esta pregunta. Quizás no aporta mucho al foro.

Comment: Bueno, excepto que el error era bastante tonto, la pregunta es muy buena, con un ejemplo reproducible bien completo.